# Error: invalid type (arg="type", value="a") web3.js

Tags: web3js, bignumber, uint256

I am trying to get the balance of user for specific token type using web3.js.

Here is my code block:

```
    var tokenContract = new web3.eth.Contract(erc20abi, tokenAddress)
    tokenContract.methods.balanceOf(accounts[0]).call().then(balance => {
              console.log(balance);
    });
```

It throws an error as soon as this function is called from web3.

Following is the error at my console:

**Uncaught (in promise) Error: invalid type (arg="type", value="a")**

```
at Object.n [as throwError] (web3.min.js:1)
at D (web3.min.js:1)
at web3.min.js:1
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at web3.min.js:1
at D (web3.min.js:1)
at e.<anonymous> (web3.min.js:1)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at e.encode (web3.min.js:1)
at a.encodeParameters (web3.min.js:1)**
```

**My web3.js version is: 1.2.7**

Here are values from the variables used:

1. accounts[0] = "0x572ACD5370909b2C0aCde66995c1BE8aC25238bE"
2. tokenAddress = "0xfd60bC45f816b575C2c938F744CFb801505824E7"
3. erc20abi =  [{
           "constant": true,
           "inputs": [],
           "name": "name",
           "outputs": [{
               "name": "",
               "type": "string"
           }],
           "payable": false,
           "type": "function"
       },
       {
           "constant": true,
           "inputs": [],
           "name": "decimals",
           "outputs": [{
               "name": "",
               "type": "uint8"
           }],
           "payable": false,
           "type": "function"
       },
       {
           "constant": true,
           "inputs": [{
               "type": "address"
           }],
           "name": "balanceOf",
           "outputs": [{
               "type": "uint256"
           }],
           "payable": false,
           "type": "function"
       },
       {
           "constant": true,
           "inputs": [],
           "name": "symbol",
           "outputs": [{
               "name": "",
               "type": "string"
           }],
           "payable": false,
           "type": "function"
       },
       {
           "constant": true,
           "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "type": "address" }],
           "name": "balanceOf",
           "outputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256", "type": "uint256" }],
           "payable": false,
           "stateMutability": "view",
           "type": "function"
       }
   ];

Comment: What line in your code triggers this error?

Comment: The problem is in `erc20abi` or in `tokenAddress` or in `accounts[0]`. Check the value of each one of these variables, and make sure that it is legal for the purpose of the corresponding variable.

Comment: ok, I have edited the question with values as well, please take a look Thanks

Comment: error triggers at line 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're using an older ABI format (or at least an unconventional one).

Change this:

```
"internalType":"address"
```

And this:

```
"internalType":"uint256"
```

To this:

```
"name":""
```

---

**UPDATE:**

It also seems that you have two `balanceOf` functions in your ABI, god knows why (maybe an attempt to support both formats). So to generalize the answer above, just use this one:

```
{
    "constant"        : true,
    "inputs"          : [{"name":"","type":"address"}],
    "name"            : "balanceOf",
    "outputs"         : [{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],
    "payable"         : false,
    "stateMutability" : "view",
    "type"            : "function"
}
```

It should be one of the elements in the `erc20abi` array of course.